# What should be preamp gain so output is at line level?

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone

this is the MIC spec:

[image]

PREAMP I'm planning has a gain of 100:
[image]

I feel that gain of 100 is too much for a line level output.

What should be correct gain?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the mic rated for the screaming level of 94dB? Normal singing or conversation levels are about 72dB.

Comment: @Audioguru Maybe because 94dB, which is 1 Pa, is extremely common, typical and one of the standard reference levels in audio/acoustic engineering, and a lot of microphone capsules and calibration microphone manufacturers simply use it because it's a common and convenient value, maybe it even comes from a standard which makes the sensitivity leves easily comparable because everyone uses 94dB. So as such, it really has little do with specific products such as microphones intended for singers, but e.g. Shure website uses 94 dB for their products unless otherwise noted, and they also use 74 dB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct gain, because it depends on which voltage levels you expect from which sound pressure levels. You might want to record people whispering across a room or a jackhammer right next to you in a steel mill. So that's why it is difficult to define.

There is no standard for what sound pressure level in dB should match some voltage level.

To make things worse, there is no stadard definition for line level either, it is whatever you want really. Or at least what your equipment requires or can accept for line level input. Modern equiment these days could use 2Vrms for full scale analog input, but your equipment might not.

However, that schematic would not work at all and would only give a flat zero output though, because it does not supply the mic with the required bias supply voltage.

Comment: Hi Justme, mic is an external module with its own bias supply voltage. -22dBV/Pa translates to 80mV. At 100, theoritical output is 8Vrms. Is this OK?

Comment: I don't know at what pressure levels you intend to use the mic, but 1 Pa is 94 dB SPL and 8 Vrms would likely do damage to a line level input, and the op-amp can't even output 8 Vrms because it only has a 12V supply. Are these limitations OK in your application?

Comment: from audio equipment datasheet - Max. input level: +26 dBu @ -10 dB gain for 0 dB FS. How to interpret this to line level voltage?

Comment: 0dBFS (maximum signal level, clipping point) is usually either +20dBu or +24dBu for professional audio gear. +20dBu is 8Vrms but generally that's delivered with a balanced signal, so 4Vrms on each leg.